# Use server API on another server

Tags: 2010

Our product owner asked me to write a plan how can we programmatically transfer changes made on our DEV site collection to UAT and finally to PRD. This involves changes in templates (both site, list and form templates) as well. So far I only have been working with the client site API, but I understand that saving and uploading templates is only doable via server API.
My question is: how can I copy a template that exists on our DEV server and upload to our UAT server with one script? Site collection relative URL's are the same.

Comment: Use a scheduled task to call a script on each server to do what you need. You can dump your template out to a shared drive and pick it up from there too.

Comment: So... for a UAT release I need 2 scripts: 1 running on the DEV server and pushes everything on a file share, and the other one running on UAT and pull them to UAT?

Comment: Yes, you can then either add a flag to a package that has been migrated or simply delete after a succesful migration.